# How can I get url of images from browser in django view

Tags: python, django, grasshopper

What should I do to allow django to read the image url from browser?

I'm learning to do a django app for getting dominant colors from images in grasshopper, so that the results could appear in rhino. which need to get images from browser. Images were downloaded in my PC could work , but not images from browser. Then I wonder if there is any python library could help with this problem?

```
jsob = {"clusters": 5,"path": 0}
    if request.method == "POST":
        try: 
            data = request.POST["data"]
            print(data)
            received = json.loads(str(data))
            jsob.update(received)
            path = jsob.get("path")
            clusters = int(jsob.get("clusters"))
            dc = DominantColors(path, clusters) 
            colors = dc.dominantColors().tolist()
            print(colors)
            print(type(colors))


            results = {"colors":colors}

            return JsonResponse(results)
  except Exception as e:
      PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

import `requests` instead of json and requests.get method take url of browser url.

```
import requests
requests.get('your urls goes here!')
```

Comment: thanks, I tired, but I can't do that. I need the outcome in grasshopper so I have to use dictionary in gh to control the url path. Could you please teach me the method I can use in this case? I tried to use   path = requests.get(jsob.get("path")),  but it couldn't work.

Comment: Din't get your problem can more describe it so that i can give you a better answer@Mindyye